# MDS with n different than 2 in Orange3

Tags: orange

In Orange 2 it was possible to perform MDS and project data onto multidimensional space rather than a plane when using the scripting library as documented in the  [docs](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/2/reference/rst/Orange.projection.mds.html).

How to do that in Orange 3? Is the feature still supported as I cannot find the MDS projection class in the data mining library, just in the visual programming part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work (set the number of desired components with n_components):

```
import Orange

data = Orange.data.Table("iris")
mds = Orange.projection.MDS(n_components=3)
projection = mds(data)
print(projection.embedding_[:5])
```

Orange3 borrows this functionality from sklearn.

Comment: That's nice. It worked, thanks. it would be good if you'd mention somewhere in the docs which sklarn functions can be used directly through orange.